# Trouble running eclipse on windows 8.1

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk

Hi I want to start developing android apps, I downloaded the ADT bundle from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html I also downloaded and installed jdk -8u5 from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html both of them I chose the 64 bit versions.
after unzipping the ADT to my c:/ drive I started eclipse the title bar wasn't eclipse it was "Resource -" the icon in the Taskbar is not from eclipse (might be a default icon), when I create a new android application project no activity_main.xml nor. Java is created and the create activity checkbox when creating the project was checked, even in the new project the title bar doesn't change to the name of the project.
when trying to create an AVD the OK button stays disabled so I can't create any AVD even using the SDK manager (Tools>Manage AVD's..).
I've tried many different eclipse downloads and nothing works as expected maybe I'm missing something along the way?
I've tried with the JRE and JDK.
I would really appreciate some help or some links to where I can download eclipse and java that would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be some problem with jdk. uninstall jdk and install jdk 1.7 and update the sdk manager install all required updates.

Comment: i did that and i can now create AVD but the title bar stays the same (Resource -), and when i create a new project no activity_main.xml is created in the layout folder

Comment: @effy i con't get u .

Comment: did u set path(environment variable)

Comment: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html.go through this nd download.adt nd install